# Setting an HTTP Timeout in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, httprequest, ruby-1.9.3, net-http

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and need to GET a URL.  I have this working with `Net::HTTP`, however, if the site is down, `Net::HTTP` ends up hanging.

While searching the internet, I've seen many people faced similar problems, all with hacky solutions.  However, many of those posts are quite old.

Requirements:

- I'd prefer using `Net::HTTP` to installing a new gem.
- I need both the Body and the Response Code. (e.g. 200)
- I do not want to `require open-uri`, since that makes global changes and raises some security issues.
- I need to GET a URL within X seconds, or return error.

Using Ruby 1.9.3, how can I GET a URL while setting a timeout?

---

To clarify, my existing code looks like:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
```

Trying to add:

```
Net::HTTP.open_timeout(1000)
```

Results in:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `open_timeout' for Net::HTTP:Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`open_timeout`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#open_timeout) attribute of the `Net::HTTP` object before making the connection.

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.open_timeout = 1000
  response = http.request_get(uri.request_uri)
end
```

Comment: Max - I'm confused how to do this.  I'm using the class method `get_request` on the `Net:HTTP` _class_; yet `open_timeout` is a method on `HTTPSession`.  Does `open_timeout` control a global setting in some Singleton?

Comment: `Net::HTTP` has a lot of confusing class methods that are basically shortcuts for creating `Net::HTTP` objects (see the source code for [`get_response`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response)). See my edit for how to create a `Net::HTTP` object yourself.

Comment: How do I get the result - the body and the http result code - using that code?

Comment: Please read the documentation. `http.request_get` returns the same thing as `Net::HTTP.get_response`

Comment: I tried it and `new` method does not work with blocks for me. I changed the `new` method to the `start` method and the whole thing worked normally.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the solutions here and on the other questions about this problem but I only got everything right with the following code, The [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) gem is a wrapper for net::http.
I needed a get that had to wait longer than the default timeout and read the response. The code is also simpler.

```
require 'open-uri'
open(url, :read_timeout => 5 * 60) do |response|
  if response.read[/Return: Ok/i]
    log "sending ok"
  else
    raise "error sending, no confirmation received"
  end
end
```