# Net::HTTP.get_response timeout

Tags: ruby, http, timeout, response

Does `Net::HTTP.get_response` timeout after some number of seconds?
If it does not, is there a way for me to add a timeout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting an HTTP Timeout in Ruby 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387405/setting-an-http-timeout-in-ruby-1-9-3)

Comment: i'm not sure if i want open_timeout, but otherwise that may be what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any method nor attributes for either Net:HTTP.get_response and/or Net:HTTP.get_print as per latest [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html). There is a [nice blog post](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2008/04/24/adding-timeout-to-nethttp-get_response/) that documents the basics for setting the timeouts though.